# Need 64Hz square wave green LED driver for a mosquito zapper

Tags: led, driver, wave, square

I have several 10 watt COB (Chip-on-Board) green LEDs which apparently are the best color to attract mosquitoes if driven at an ideal pulsing square wave frequency of 64 Hz.

I was going to use a transformer power supply with a half-wave rectifier but that would give me 60Hz half sine wave, not the preferable square wave.

Can anyone show me a simple circuit with off-the-shelf components that I can assemble or buy?

Comment: What voltage do the LED arrays require?

Comment: even if 64 is ideal, 60 sounds a pretty good second best, and worth trying for the simplicity

Comment: One beginner-friendly approach would be a 555 timer set up for 64 Hz 50% duty-cycle driving a MOSFET to power the LEDs.  Search for those words and you will find hundreds of examples on the web.

Comment: 555 + MOSFET and resistor for current limiting?

Comment: The COB LEDs are 12V. 60 Hz may also be attractive but I wonder if the half sine wave would be "flickering" enough to make mosquitoes think that it is an animal moving through brush compared to a square wave. I'm not sure if LEDs light output drops to zero long enough when the voltage is zero between pulses. One problem is that 12V AC transformer power supplies are rare compared to 12V DC switching ones.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the LEDs? 12V sounds like they may have some circuitry on board.

Comment: Please provide a datasheet for your LEDs. There's some important stuff needed to figure out a solution, namely nominal voltage and current. These influence the approach taken to drive them.

Comment: If you add a 1mF capacitor parallel to the Led (fed by a half wave rectifier) you will get what you want

Comment: @MissMulan That sounds like the opposite of what they want.  They want square wave pulses, not smooth lighting.

Comment: Just because you are using line frequency for convenience, the drive to the LEDs is not limited to half-sines.  They easily can be driven with square pulses.

Comment: Do you want to build a circuit, or wire together pre-fab modules?

Comment: Frankly, I doubt that going from square wave to half-sine will make any noticeable difference.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Possibly the square wave has harmonics that might tend to stimulate the mosquito fast visual receptors better than a sine. It’d be an interesting study to see.

Comment: The 64Hz Figure seems to come from this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5216328/ . 64Hz yielded the best results of the tested frequencies which were 25Hz, 32Hz, 64 Hz, 128Hz, 256Hz and 512Hz (They used UV, not green!). So no, 64Hz is not "the best Frequency" but only the best of the tested ones (and the Testing is pretty limited!)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems to solve besides making the square wave.

**LED Drive**

Let's talk about your LEDs for a moment. You state they are 10W COB type, nominally 12V. You didn’t provide a datasheet, but we can do some estimating anyway.

This class of high-power LED needs about 800-900mA of **regulated** current, with a forward voltage of about 12V for each LED COB set.

Problem is, like all LEDs, these large high-wattage COB units are **current** devices, and their  forward voltage varies from unit to unit as well as with temperature and forward current. Because of these characteristics, **you cannot connect them to a supply without current limiting**, otherwise you will **destroy** the LEDs.

Next problem: how to drive them efficiently? The trick is to **minimize IR drop losses** as much as you can. One way is to **connect them in series** and feed them with a higher, yet current-controlled voltage.

Say you want to run 3 of these for a 30W light (that's pretty bright. is that your intention?) Connect them in series, then drive them together with a **36V LED dimmable driver** rated for 800mA or so. These modules are available with a variety of voltage inputs, 9-15V boost up to 36V is common, as are supplies that work directly off AC power. I'll leave the searching and shopping up to you. Meanwell is a quality vendor for this.

Now, why **dimmable**? Because we will use the LED driver's dimming input to switch this thing on and off at your desired 64Hz.

**Making 64 Hz**

So now we get to your question: How to make 64 Hz? The NE555 timer (or even better, the [LMC555 CMOS version](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf)) can do this easily. The 555 frequency is set with just a simple RC network. It can also be easily adjusted for duty cycle with the appropriate circuit - this might be worth experimenting with to reduce power consumption. Finally, the 555 can run directly off 12V, which could simplify your power supply.

Could you use a microcontroller? Sure, but why? It's definitely more work. Software, power supply, support circuits… more than is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in my opinion is to use an Arduino board with a FET switch. Using this solution does only require minor shopping, coding skills and tools.

**Recommendation:** In my opinion you should opt for this solution. I did do a quick search for you.

```
#define pinToUse 5
#define delayToUse 1000
#define Busywait(n){while(volatile unsigned int_32t cnt = 0; cnt<n; cnt++){asm("nop");}

void setup(void){
  pinMode(pinToUse ,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(void){
  digitalWrite(pinToUse ,HIGH);
  Busywait(delayToUse);
  digitalWrite(pinToUse ,LOW);
  Busywait(delayToUse);
}
```

Here is you code.

[Here is your Arduino quick-start](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUno)

[Here is your controller - IDE is easy to use, free an well documented](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/dfrobot/DFR0010/6588448)

[Here is your power supply providing 12V for the LEDs and 5V for the Arduino](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/RPT-65E/7706130)

[Here is your switch. Did select a high-side as it was the cheapest](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/EV-VN7050AS/5308006)

Connect like:

*Image of initial schematic removed*

**Please be careful when handling mains wiring!**

**EDIT 1:** As per comment from @hacktastical current limiting and balancing is needed to connect multiple LEDs in parallel. The current limiting is also required with a single LED. This can be done by using a series resistor.

U_drop = 12V - V_Led (Consult the datasheet to select the voltage drop across the diode at your desired current flow - current sets the brightness)

I_led = The active forward current you selected.

R = U_drop/I_led. Connect between High-Side switch and LED

**Take care:** P = U_drop x I_Led.
This will waste a lot of power in heat tough - you could consider to use a 5V supply for the LEDs too - this will simplify the power supply requirements and reduce the voltage drop and therefore power loss across the resistors.

**Take care:** The minimum Voltage is 4V as this is required for the high-side switch module.

Huge shoutout to @hacktastical !

**EDIT 2:** Did change the schematic to adapt the suggestions received.

[image: Schematic Rev2]

Comment: The two secondary circuits need to share a common ground. Also, the AC needs to be rectified for both, and regulated for the Arduino.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Please see the recommended power supply https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/RPT-65E/7706130

Comment: No power supply shows up in your schematic. That is why I mentioned it.

Comment: Lots of issues here. Current limiting? Enough drive for multiple **10W** FETs (about 800mA each)? The fact that a p-JFET needs its gate biased **above** source? Please revisit.

Comment: J271 is an obsolete JFET capable of -6mA.

Comment: @hacktastical Please read the documentation on the recommended parts carefully. The power Supply does provide 54W on its 12V rail. So up to 5 LEDs can be connected. If this is not enough just use a different style - as I said: recommended. The High-Side Switch is logic-compatible (3V/5V). You do have a valid point in regards to the current limiting though. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent it's not about the power supply. It's about the dinky FET. Speaking of which, the FET has a pinch-off of as high as 4.5V. That is, the gate needs to be **above** 12V by Vgs to turn it off. As shown it will never turn off. Even worse, **the FET p-n junction will be forward biased, frying the Arduino.** If your intention was a logic-level switch, then a low-side n-MOSFET of adequate size would work.

Comment: @hacktastical The J271 is a sample part within the schematic to illustrate the connections to the recommended "High-side driver with MultiSense analog feedback for automotive applications" module to be used - as recommended per link to Digikey. This device is CMOS compatibel to control its advanced internal features. Please consult Page 3 Table 1. https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/50/3c/4d/5f/7a/6f/41/0c/DM00157092.pdf/files/DM00157092.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00157092.pdf

Please read the docmentation provided carefuly. Have a good one.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent If your intention was to show a high-side load control switch, then draw it as a box. In the big picture, you're getting a lot of negative feedback here from some very experienced people. That should be a pretty strong indication that your answer needs work.

Comment: If that is easy, I'd hate to see complicated.

Comment: Wow, Lots of solutions, thank you.

Comment: There is no spec sheet for my 10W COB LEDs and will probably arrange them 60 degrees apart to provide 360 degree coverage in a bug zapper with the UV lamp removed. Or will use a 12V PC case fan to suck mosquitoes to their death in a trap.

Comment: I have several dimmers of this type: https://www.amazon.ca/weideer-Controller-Adjustable-Brightness-Screwdriver/dp/B093FD3DL2/ref=rvi_sccl_4/139-8697829-5047306?pd_rd_w=D5JyS&pf_rd_p=8b4d8c20-8e51-4634-a76f-c00a1995a502&pf_rd_r=TPKKXWCQBE1FY0HTCK0H&pd_rd_r=759b9dd2-1d45-4fa2-a00f-06c936bbcf3d&pd_rd_wg=Di7uy&pd_rd_i=B093FD3DL2&psc=1 but will it alone dim down to 64HZ?